# How to find a number between two particular strings?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following as a string:

```
{
   "_matrix":[
      {
         "__FRAMEWORK_ANY_SPEC__":"namesdeleted.mumbojumbo`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
         "value":0
      },
      {
         "__FRAMEWORK_ANY_SPEC__":"namesdeleted.mumbojumbo`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
         "value":1
      },
      {
         "__FRAMEWORK_ANY_SPEC__":"namesdeleted.mumbojumbo`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
         "value":0
      },
      {
         "__FRAMEWORK_ANY_SPEC__":"namesdeleted.mumbojumbo`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
         "value":-1
      },
      {
         "__FRAMEWORK_ANY_SPEC__":"namesdeleted.mumbojumbo`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
         "value":-.1
      },
      {
         "__FRAMEWORK_ANY_SPEC__":"namesdeleted.mumbojumbo`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
         "value":1.1
      },
      {
         "__FRAMEWORK_ANY_SPEC__":"namesdeleted.mumbojumbo`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
         "value":0
      },
      {
         "__FRAMEWORK_ANY_SPEC__":"namesdeleted.mumbojumbo`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
         "value":0
      },
      {
         "__FRAMEWORK_ANY_SPEC__":"namesdeleted.mumbojumbo`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
         "value":.1
      },
      {
         "__FRAMEWORK_ANY_SPEC__":"namesdeleted.mumbojumbo`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
         "value":0
      },
      {
         "__FRAMEWORK_ANY_SPEC__":"namesdeleted.mumbojumbo`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
         "value":1
      },
      {
         "__FRAMEWORK_ANY_SPEC__":"namesdeleted.mumbojumbo`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
         "value":0
      },
      {
         "__FRAMEWORK_ANY_SPEC__":"namesdeleted.mumbojumbo`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
         "value":0
      },
      {
         "__FRAMEWORK_ANY_SPEC__":"namesdeleted.mumbojumbo`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
         "value":0
      },
      {
         "__FRAMEWORK_ANY_SPEC__":"namesdeleted.mumbojumbo`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
         "value":0
      },
      {
         "__FRAMEWORK_ANY_SPEC__":"namesdeleted.mumbojumbo`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
         "value":1
      }
   ]
}
```

My main I need to collect all the numbers after `"value":` and between the next `}` The value can be any decimal/integer number.

I would personally also like it to work with scientific notation *if possible*.

My current regex is :

```
(?<=("value": ))(?:\d*.)?\d+(?=})
```

I'm using it in C#, so `?<=` is valid.

My current regex is able to filter the following types of numbers:

- 1
- -1
- 1.1
- .1

I need it to also accommodate for:

- -.1
- scientific notation, so if there is a way to capture everything between `"value":` and the next `}`

Comment: Your example looks like JSON. Can't you just parse the JSON and get your value?

Comment: This string is coming from unmanaged code. I can't really use anything but string manipulation or regexp in C#.

Comment: @BikerDude: Yes you can. You can parse it to a matching class(es) on your end and get your data from there.

Comment: It's not valid JSON (some of the values are unquoted). But it's eminently parseable; in Python, for example, `ast.literal_eval()` does the job.

Comment: Instead of being sorry format the string

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not too regexperienced with programming in anything but matlab. I also know that I don't exactly have an equivalent class, and this is coming from a section I have no control over.  
I would also like to say that my end goal is to convert this string to a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: You are right, the `.1` without the leading zero trips it up. It's badly formatted JSON.

Comment: @SirRufo I wasn't sure what all would be needed. I can format the string.

Comment: I already updated your question with a formatted representation of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expressed in the comments, this looks like JSON and you ought to parse it rather than try to use regex. But if you must use regex, something like this seems to work:

```
(?<=("value": ))(?:-?\d*\.?)?\d+(?=})
```

The changes are to add `-?` to cover the optional minus sign and changing your `.` which I assume was supposed to match the decimal to `\.` because `.` matches *any character* in regex, so it needs to be escaped. Then I added the `?` to make it optional.

https://regex101.com/r/drNrDS/1

If you wanted to support number like `1.1e10` and `1.1e-3`, then you just need to add a few more optional matches:

```
(?<=("value": ))(?:-?\d*\.?)?\d+(?:e|e-)?\d*(?=})
```

So we've added `(?:e|e-)?\d*` which matches `e` or `e-` followed by some digits.

Comment: Anything that could work for scientific notations as well?

Comment: Don't see why mine wouldn't work for this, see my updated answer for a solution using an inline modifier

Comment: @DNKROZ: I don't think anybody said that your's wouldn't work. Although your's is much more permissive. For example, it would match `"value":Foo}`. Even your link has `1.es3` which shouldn't match since it's not a number.

Comment: @MattBurland No i know, I was referring to the scientific notation before you posted your edit. Yep matches anything in between the 2 values which is what the question asked for.
You're right, yours is a lot more specific

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will do the trick:-

`/(?s)(?<="value":)(.+?)(?=})/g` (Using inline modifier)

For example: https://regex101.com/r/drNrDS/2

[image]

Comment: Works! But beaten to the buzzer.

Comment: @DNKROZ Which tool did you used for the picture?